# Send One Message to only one of Multiple Consumers in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a somewhat unique use case with RabbitMQ and I'm not sure how to go about solving the problem. I want to have one queue with multiple consumers bound to it and then have RabbitMQ send out one message to only one consumer at at time and wait for an ACK before sending out another message to any other consumer.

I realize this kills throughput and can essentially starve the other consumers but for me that's OK. The reason for this odd use case is that the service that the consumers talk to can only handle one concurrent request at a time so I need a way to limit this but consumers can also die unexpectedly and I need another consumer to pick up processing the messages if this happens. I know there is the `prefetch` option but that still allows multiple users to get a and exclusive queues but I'm not sure those accomplish what I want. Is it possible configure RabbitMQ to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No; there is no way to limit competing consumers on the same queue such that there is one and only one message in process across all consumers until the ack is received.

A similar question came up some time ago; I don't remember if it was here or in the Spring forums but I believe the solution was to have the consumers acquire a global lock of some kind, using something like hazelcast, or even a simple database table row lock (with prefetch=1 so each consumer had only one "in process" message which was processed as and when each one got the lock).